# How to place a DOM object within a data attribute with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

**Breakdown:**

So basically, I am using Twiiter Bootstrap popover.

The way that `popover` works is that DOM elements (or content) must be within a data attriubute called `data-content` so that the popover can display this within its contents when called.

I am using a small jQuery plugin to generate a mini chart ([Peity](http://benpickles.github.io/peity/)). I am attempting to save this chart as a variable, then paste the variable within the `data-content` attribute of the element that `popover` is on. The DOM object must be placed inside of the `data-content` for the `popover` to determine where to be placed. If the chart is placed directly into the `popover-content` class, the popover will not know where to place itself (since it has a position of absolute), and it will have in incorrect `top` value.

**My attempt:**

I have tried to initiate the popover for a specific class (that is applied on many `td` elements). Once the popover is created for all of these, I then create the hover event.

```
function createLargeGraphs() {
    //Initiating the popover for every td
    $('td.chartSection').each(function () {
        $(this).popover({
            placement: 'top',
            trigger: 'hover',
            html: true,
            container: $(this),
            delay: {
                hide: 500
            },
        });
    });

    //When hovered, create the full graph with data
    $('td.chartSection').on('mouseenter', function () {
        displayLargeGraph($(this));
    });
}
```

I then pass through the hovered element to another function to be processed. This is where the data is created (Peity requires a `span` with comma separated numbers for its data. This data is currently dummy data.) within a span, inside the `popover` content. After the data is accessible, the Peity plugin then converts this data into a chart that is saved as a variable and moved into the `data-content` attribute.

```
function displayLargeGraph($elem) {
    var $popoverContent = $elem.find('.popover-content');

    //Create the span with the data values comma separated. This is a requirement for the Peity plguin.
    var theSpan = '<span class="largeChart' + chartCounter + '">5,3,9,6,5,9,7,3,5,2,5,3,9,6,5,9,7,3,5,2</span>';

    $popoverContent.append(theSpan);

    //Creating the chart and saving as a variable
    var $chart = $(".largeChart" + chartCounter).peity("line", {
        height: 159,
        width: 600,
    });

    $elem.attr('data-content', $chart);

    //Adding one to the chartCounter variable for next use
    chartCounter++;
}
```

**Whats going wrong:**

The chart is not being placed within the `data-content` attribute successfully. Instead, within the source, it is `[object Object]`.

How can I place this into the `data-content` as its full DOM source such as:

```
<svg class="peity" height="159" width="600"><polygon fill="#c6d9fd" points="0 158 0 70.72222222222221 31.57894736842105 105.83333333333333 63.1578947368421 0.5 94.73684210526315 53.16666666666666 126.3157894736842 70.72222222222221 157.89473684210526 0.5 189.4736842105263 35.6111111111111 221.05263157894737 105.83333333333333 252.6315789473684 70.72222222222221 284.2105263157895 123.38888888888889 315.7894736842105 70.72222222222221 347.36842105263156 105.83333333333333 378.9473684210526 0.5 410.52631578947364 53.16666666666666 442.10526315789474 70.72222222222221 473.6842105263158 0.5 505.2631578947368 35.6111111111111 536.8421052631579 105.83333333333333 568.421052631579 70.72222222222221 600 123.38888888888889 600 158"></polygon > < polyline fill = "transparent" points = "0 70.72222222222221 31.57894736842105 105.83333333333333 63.1578947368421 0.5 94.73684210526315 53.16666666666666 126.3157894736842 70.72222222222221 157.89473684210526 0.5 189.4736842105263 35.6111111111111 221.05263157894737 105.83333333333333 252.6315789473684 70.72222222222221 284.2105263157895 123.38888888888889 315.7894736842105 70.72222222222221 347.36842105263156 105.83333333333333 378.9473684210526 0.5 410.52631578947364 53.16666666666666 442.10526315789474 70.72222222222221 473.6842105263158 0.5 505.2631578947368 35.6111111111111 536.8421052631579 105.83333333333333 568.421052631579 70.72222222222221 600 123.38888888888889" stroke = "#4d89f9" stroke - width = "1" stroke - linecap = "square" > < /polyline></svg >
```

---

Notes: Within the live version there will be hundreds (if not thousands) of these table elements. That is why I am only trying to create the data and popover if it is requested/hovered.

My counter (`chartCounter`) is currently getting extremely large since the function `displayLargeGraph` is run every time the element is hovered, even when the chart already exists. Just ignore this as I am in the process of only running the function when no chart for that element exists.

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/gAyN7/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.popover()` method takes an options object and in that options object, you can specify the content as a function that is called when it wants the content.  Then, you can dynamically generate the content upon demand when that function is called.

Since you have custom content that you probably don't want to pregenerate all the HTML for, this is probably the way you want to go.

```
function createLargeGraphs() {
    //Initiating the popover for every td
    $('td.chartSection').each(function () {
        $(this).popover({
            placement: 'top',
            trigger: 'hover',
            html: true,
            container: $(this),
            delay: {
                hide: 500
            },
            content: function() {
                // create your content here
            }
        });
    });

    //When hovered, create the full graph with data
    $('td.chartSection').on('mouseenter', function () {
        displayLargeGraph($(this));
    });
}
```

Comment: This would definitely be the best way to go. Although, I am still a little confused on how to implement it into my current code. So the `content` option would contain the function that would create the graph? Then what would the `displayLargeGraph` function do?

Answer (score 1):

Well, $chart will refer to the .largeChart element. What you want is the element generated by peity. Without delving into the documentation of that plug-in (to see if there's a better solution), from inspection you can simply replace:

```
$elem.attr('data-content', $chart);
```

with

```
if ($chart.siblings('.peity').length) {
    $elem.attr('data-content', $chart.siblings('.peity')[0].outerHTML);
}
```

Comment: Seems to not work unfortunately, but I see where you're going. Even getting an error when I run - `console.log($chart.siblings('.peity')[0].outerHTML);`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `data-*` attributes, I'd use a `key => value` array, where:

key: `".largeChart" + chartCounter`

value: `$chart`

Comment: But `Twitter Bootstrap` runs their `popover` with data attributes only?

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach could be using [`jQuery's .data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/):

```
$elem.data('content', $chart);
```

in replacement of:

```
$elem.attr('data-content', $chart);
```